# Ionic 3.x : cordova run ios throws error ENOENT

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, directory, ionic3

Fist of all I'm using Ionic 3 on macOS Sierra.

I'm trying to test my app using `cordova run iOS` . If I do, I get the following error message:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-SE, 10.3 simulator
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=53):
Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted
Software caused connection abort
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=53):
Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted
Software caused connection abort
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/jan/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/C0954A6B-4791-448E-8D0A-9E875301BD8B/system.log
```

The simulation loads, but the simulator is black.
I googled this problem and found this https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/4052 but doing "sudo chown ..." doesn't help me.
Any idea how to fix this error?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was that I installed some stuff using sudo and other stuff not using sudo, which resulted in conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

**@suraj**

You maybe need to remove platform and re-add.
And not run the ionic / cordova command as sudo.

You should run as your user, e.g.

ionic cordova run ios ......

And **not**

***<s>sudo</s>*** ionic cordova run ios .....

If you need to run as sudo, this cause the problem. Because run as sudo, it changes owner of folders and files to root.

To fix this problem, I first did to fix all execution permissions to my user, and not only for root / sudo.

I hope this helps you!